# Applying for US visitor visa from Canada

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, canada, applications

I am an indian passport holder working in Canada on work permit. My wife will be joining me on V1 visitor visa. We were thinking of applying for US visitor visa from Canada. Though i have proof of address, utilities on my name in Canada, my wife does not have any of these documents. She will have her employer letter for leave, salary slips and other supporting documents. Will we be able to apply for US visitor visa from Canada for both of us?

Answer (score 3):

It should be fine.  However, if your wife resides elsewhere she might want to apply for the US visa there, before traveling to Canada.  The US accepts visa applications in any consulate but advises that the consulate responsible for the place of residence is best situated to evaluate an applicant's circumstances.